# Terminal won't print "Refresh" in terminal

Tags: application-development, python

I have a slight problem today with my Ubuntu app. I've been following a YouTube tutorial. I've provided the link below with the rest of the links provided to help you find out the cause of the problem.

I am using a program called 'quickly' which is a program that helps you to create 'apps' aka programs to be exact.

This program allows you to press the "Refresh" button, then it should generate a word saying "Refresh". When I click the button, nothing happens. I don't understand where I have gone wrong and this is where I need some help.

Links:

- Youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg (13:00 for the source.)
- Source link: http://mysticpaste.com/view/X5iBOZYUD4?9 (The code.)

Comment: Where is this mybrowser stuff coming from?  Some random github project like this: https://github.com/jcrubino/gtk_browser ?

Comment: @hbdgaf Yes, that's it.

Comment: I would start from scratch instead of basing work on a git tree that contains pyc files.  .gitignore is a beautiful thing.  It's really not so bad to use.

Comment: I've been looking for a video showing you a easy-simple way of creating a web browser and found that one.

Comment: Does it run? I would think that line 26 should be indented to be in the finish_initializing method. Also, the "clicked" signal from the control need to be connected to the method (unless that is done somewhere else with a named method and an autoconnect).